# How can I generically tell if a Java Class is a primitive type?

Tags: java

Is there any way to take a Class and determine if it represents a primitive type (is there a solution that doesn't require specifically enumerating all the primitive types)?

NOTE: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180097/dynamically-find-the-class-that-represents-a-primitive-java-type).  I'm asking basically the opposite.  I have the Class, I want to know if it's a primitive.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a method on the Class object called [isPrimitive](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive()).

Answer (score 7):

[Class.isPrimitive()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive()) will tell you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This method will also check whether it's a wrapper of a primitive type as well:

```
/**
* Checks first whether it is primitive and then whether it's wrapper is a primitive wrapper. Returns true
* if either is true
*
* @param c
* @return whether it's a primitive type itself or it's a wrapper for a primitive type
*/
public static boolean isPrimitive(Class c) {
  if (c.isPrimitive()) {
    return true;
  } else if (c == Byte.class
          || c == Short.class
          || c == Integer.class
          || c == Long.class
          || c == Float.class
          || c == Double.class
          || c == Boolean.class
          || c == Character.class) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Use Number.class.isAssignableFrom(c) instead of checking equality with all Number subtypes

Comment: @digitalillusion That would also include non-wrapper types like `BigInteger`, which is a `Number` too

Comment: `return c.isPrimitive() || c.getSuperclass() == Number.class || c == Boolean.class || c == Character.class;` is an easier solution