# Callback functions in Java

Tags: java, callback, function-pointers

Is there a way to pass a call back function in a Java method?

The behavior I'm trying to mimic is a .Net Delegate being passed to a function.

I've seen people suggesting creating a separate object but that seems overkill, however I am aware that sometimes overkill is the only way to do things.

Comment: It's overkill because Java is nonfunctional (that's supposed to be a pun...).

Comment: Another java 8 example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319787/how-to-specify-function-types-for-void-not-void-methods-in-java8

Answer (score 176, accepted):

If you mean somthing like .NET anonymous delegate, I think Java's anonymous class can be used as well.

```
public class Main {

    public interface Visitor{
        int doJob(int a, int b);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Visitor adder = new Visitor(){
            public int doJob(int a, int b) {
                return a + b;
            }
        };

        Visitor multiplier = new Visitor(){
            public int doJob(int a, int b) {
                return a*b;
            }
        };

        System.out.println(adder.doJob(10, 20));
        System.out.println(multiplier.doJob(10, 20));

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the canonical method since Java 1.0.

Comment: I've been usign this, it's slioghtly more verbose than what I'd like, but it works.

Comment: @Omar, agreed.  I've come back to Java after a long stint with C# and really miss lambdas/delegates.  Come on Java!

Comment: @DrewNoakes, good news is, [Java 8](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/) has lambdas (mostly)...

Comment: since you've defined the interface Visitor with a single method, you can pass lambdas that match instead of it.

Answer (score 76):

Since Java 8, there are lambda and method references:

- [Oracle Docs: Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)
- [Oracle Docs: Method References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

For example, if you want a functional interface `A -> B`, you can use:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public MyClass {
    public static String applyFunction(String name, Function<String,String> function){
        return function.apply(name);
    }
}
```

And here is how you can call it:

```
MyClass.applyFunction("42", str -> "the answer is: " + str);
// returns "the answer is: 42"
```

Also you can pass class method. For example:

```
@Value // lombok
public class PrefixAppender {
    private String prefix;

    public String addPrefix(String suffix){
        return prefix +":"+suffix;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
PrefixAppender prefixAppender= new PrefixAppender("prefix");
MyClass.applyFunction("some text", prefixAppender::addPrefix);
// returns "prefix:some text"
```

**Note**:

Here I used the functional interface `Function<A,B>`, but there are many others in the package `java.util.function`. Most notable ones are

- `Supplier`: `void -> A`
- `Consumer`: `A -> void`
- `BiConsumer`: `(A,B) -> void`
- `Function`: `A -> B`
- `BiFunction`: `(A,B) -> C`

and many others that specialize on some of the input/output type. Then, if it doesn't provide the one you need, you can create your own `FunctionalInterface`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Function3<In1, In2, In3, Out> { // (In1,In2,In3) -> Out
    public Out apply(In1 in1, In2 in2, In3 in3);
}
```

Example of use:

```
String computeAnswer(Function3<String, Integer, Integer, String> f){
    return f.apply("6x9=", 6, 9);
}

computeAnswer((question, a, b) -> question + "42");
// "6*9=42"
```

And you can also do that with thrown exception:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface FallibleFunction<In, Out, Ex extends Exception> {
    Out get(In input) throws Ex;
}
public <Ex extends IOException> String yo(FallibleFunction<Integer, String, Ex> f) throws Ex {
    return f.get(42);
}
```

Comment: For CallBacks, it would be better to write your own functional interface since each callback type would usually have multiple syntaxes.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. If one of the classes in `java.util.function` is what you are looking for, then you're good to go. Then you can play with generics for the I/O. (?)

Comment: You didn't get me, what I said is about translating C++ code which uses callback functions to Java 8, There, for each unique function pointer, you have to create a Functional interface in Java, since there will be more parameters in the real production code.

Comment: My conclusion is that most of the time, you are required to write your own functional interfaces since the default provided ones, in `java.util.function` aren't sufficient.

Comment: Then use scala, much simpler for functional interface :-)

Comment: I added a note on existing functional interfaces and how to create new ones

Comment: Thanks, for very interesting answer. Please update "Note" section and mention that not all interfaces are called using `f.apply()` ... in my case I used `BiConsumer` and it is called using `f.accept()` (I did not tested other ones how they are called, maybe you know it)

Answer (score 45):

For simplicity, you can use a **Runnable**:

```
private void runCallback(Runnable callback)
{
    // Run callback
    callback.run();
}
```

Usage:

```
runCallback(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Running callback
    }
});
```

or with Java8 lambdas

```
runCallback(() -> {
    // Running callback
});
```

Comment: I like this because I don't need to create a new interface or class just to do a simple callback. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: `public interface SimpleCallback {
    void callback(Object... objects);
}`
This is quite straightforward and could be useful you need to pass some params too.

Comment: @cprcrack no way to pass a value in the run() function?

Comment: The beauty about this is that you can use a short lambda expression when you pass the function, i.e. `runCallback(() -> { /* running callback */ })`. This is great for simple stuff. For more complex stuff I recommend to look into `CompletableFuture`s.

Answer (score 30):

yet i see there is most preferred way which was what i was looking for.. it's basically derived from these answers but i had to manipulate it to more more redundant and efficient.. **and i think everybody looking for what i come up with**

#### To the point::

first make an Interface *that simple*

```java
public interface myCallback {
    void onSuccess();
    void onError(String err);
}
```

now to make this callback run when ever you wish to do to handle the results - ***more likely after async call and you wanna run some stuff which depends on these reuslts***

```java
// import the Interface class here

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // call your method
        doSomething("list your Params", new myCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // no errors
                System.out.println("Done");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String err) {
                // error happen
                System.out.println(err);
            }
        });
    }

    private void doSomething(String param, // some params..
                             myCallback callback) {
        // now call onSuccess whenever you want if results are ready
        if(results_success)
            callback.onSuccess();
        else
            callback.onError(someError);
    }

}
```

`doSomething` is the function that takes some time you wanna add a callback to it to notify you when the results came, add the call back interface as a parameter to this method

#### hope my point is clear, enjoy ;)

Comment: this is very easy

Comment: best solution, very understandable

Answer (score 17):

A little nitpicking:

> I've seem people suggesting creating a
>   separate object but that seems
>   overkill

Passing a callback includes creating a separate object in pretty much any OO language, so it can hardly be considered overkill. What you probably mean is that in Java, it requires you to create a separate class, which is more verbose (and more resource-intensive) than in languages with explicit first-class functions or closures. However, anonymous classes at least reduce the verbosity and can be used inline.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant. With 30 or so events you end up with 30 classes.

Answer (score 14):

This is very easy in Java 8 with lambdas.

```
public interface Callback {
    void callback();
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methodThatExpectsACallback(() -> System.out.println("I am the callback."));
    }
    private static void methodThatExpectsACallback(Callback callback){
        System.out.println("I am the method.");
        callback.callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it be like this in case with argument? https://pastebin.com/KFFtXPNA

Comment: Yep. Any amount of arguments (or none) will work as long as proper lambda syntax is maintained.

Answer (score 7):

I found the idea of implementing using the reflect library interesting and came up with this which I think works quite well. The only down side is losing the compile time check that you are passing valid parameters.

```
public class CallBack {
    private String methodName;
    private Object scope;

    public CallBack(Object scope, String methodName) {
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object... parameters) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method = scope.getClass().getMethod(methodName, getParameterClasses(parameters));
        return method.invoke(scope, parameters);
    }

    private Class[] getParameterClasses(Object... parameters) {
        Class[] classes = new Class[parameters.length];
        for (int i=0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            classes[i] = parameters[i].getClass();
        }
        return classes;
    }
}
```

You use it like this

```
public class CallBackTest {
    @Test
    public void testCallBack() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        CallBack callBack = new CallBack(testClass, "hello");
        callBack.invoke();
        callBack.invoke("Fred");
    }

    public class TestClass {
        public void hello() {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }

        public void hello(String name) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks a bit like overkill (/me ducks)

Comment: depends on the number of use and the size of the project: overkill for a few-class project, practical on a large one.

Comment: Also, take a look at the answer of @monnoo

Answer (score 5):

A method is not (yet) a first-class object in Java; you can't pass a function pointer as a callback. Instead, create an object (which usually implements an interface) that contains the method you need and pass that.

Proposals for closures in Java—which would provide the behavior you are looking for—have been made, but none will be included in the upcoming Java 7 release.

Comment: "A method is not (yet) a first-class object in Java" -- well, there's the method class[1], of which you can certainly pass around instances.  It's not the clean, idiomatic, OO code that you'd expect from java, but it might be expedient.  Certainly something to consider, though.

[1] http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Answer (score 4):

When I need this kind of functionality in Java, I usually use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  It does imply an extra object, but I think it's a clean way to go, and is a widely understood pattern, which helps with code readability.

Answer (score 4):

Check the closures how they have been implemented in the lambdaj library. They actually have a behavior very similar to C# delegates:

http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/Closures

Answer (score 3):

You also can do the`Callback` using the `Delegate` pattern:

Callback.java

```
public interface Callback {
    void onItemSelected(int position);
}
```

PagerActivity.java

```
public class PagerActivity implements Callback {

    CustomPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    public PagerActivity() {
        mPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int position) {
        // Do something
        System.out.println("Item " + postion + " selected")
    }
}
```

CustomPagerAdapter.java

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter {
    private static final int DEFAULT_POSITION = 1;
    public CustomPagerAdapter(Callback callback) {
        callback.onItemSelected(DEFAULT_POSITION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried using java.lang.reflect to implement 'callback', here's a sample:

```
package StackOverflowQ443708_JavaCallBackTest;

import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class MyTimer
{
    ExecutorService EXE =
        //Executors.newCachedThreadPool ();
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor ();

    public static void PrintLine ()
    {
        System.out.println ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    public void SetTimer (final int timeout, final Object obj, final String methodName, final Object... args)
    {
        SetTimer (timeout, obj, false, methodName, args);
    }
    public void SetTimer (final int timeout, final Object obj, final boolean isStatic, final String methodName, final Object... args)
    {
        Class<?>[] argTypes = null;
        if (args != null)
        {
            argTypes = new Class<?> [args.length];
            for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
            {
                argTypes[i] = args[i].getClass ();
            }
        }

        SetTimer (timeout, obj, isStatic, methodName, argTypes, args);
    }
    public void SetTimer (final int timeout, final Object obj, final String methodName, final Class<?>[] argTypes, final Object... args)
    {
        SetTimer (timeout, obj, false, methodName, argTypes, args);
    }
    public void SetTimer (final int timeout, final Object obj, final boolean isStatic, final String methodName, final Class<?>[] argTypes, final Object... args)
    {
        EXE.execute (
            new Runnable()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    Class<?> c;
                    Method method;
                    try
                    {
                        if (isStatic) c = (Class<?>)obj;
                        else c = obj.getClass ();

                        System.out.println ("Wait for " + timeout + " seconds to invoke " + c.getSimpleName () + "::[" + methodName + "]");
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep (timeout);
                        System.out.println ();
                        System.out.println ("invoking " + c.getSimpleName () + "::[" + methodName + "]...");
                        PrintLine ();
                        method = c.getDeclaredMethod (methodName, argTypes);
                        method.invoke (obj, args);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        PrintLine ();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
    public void ShutdownTimer ()
    {
        EXE.shutdown ();
    }
}

public class CallBackTest
{
    public void onUserTimeout ()
    {
        System.out.println ("onUserTimeout");
    }
    public void onTestEnd ()
    {
        System.out.println ("onTestEnd");
    }
    public void NullParameterTest (String sParam, int iParam)
    {
        System.out.println ("NullParameterTest: String parameter=" + sParam + ", int parameter=" + iParam);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        CallBackTest test = new CallBackTest ();
        MyTimer timer = new MyTimer ();

        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), test, "onUserTimeout");
        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), test, "onTestEnd");
        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), test, "A-Method-Which-Is-Not-Exists");    // java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), System.out, "println", "this is an argument of System.out.println() which is called by timer");
        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), System.class, true, "currentTimeMillis");
        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), System.class, true, "currentTimeMillis", "Should-Not-Pass-Arguments");    // java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), String.class, true, "format", "%d %X", 100, 200); // java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), String.class, true, "format", "%d %X", new Object[]{100, 200});

        timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), test, "NullParameterTest", new Class<?>[]{String.class, int.class}, null, 888);

        timer.ShutdownTimer ();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you pass null as an arg?

Comment: @TWiStErRob, in this sample, it would be like `timer.SetTimer ((int)(Math.random ()*10), System.out, "printf", "%s: [%s]", new Object[]{"null test", null});`. output will be `null test: [null]`

Comment: Wouldn't it NPE on `args[i].getClass()`? My point is that it doesn't work if you select method based on argument types. It works with `String.format`, but may not work with something else which accepts `null`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob, Good point! I've added a function which can manually pass `argTypes` array, so now we can pass `null` argument/parameter without NullPointerException occured. Sample output: `NullParameterTest: String parameter=null, int parameter=888`

Answer (score 2):

I've recently started doing something like this:

```
public class Main {
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface NotDotNetDelegate {
        int doSomething(int a, int b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // in java 8 (lambdas):
        System.out.println(functionThatTakesDelegate((a, b) -> {return a*b;} , 10, 20));

    }

    public static int functionThatTakesDelegate(NotDotNetDelegate del, int a, int b) {
        // ...
        return del.doSomething(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with java 8 this task is kinda easy, if you want to use callback in multi-thread scenario you can do something similar like the following:

```
public  void methodA (int n, IntConsumer consumer) {
    
    // create a thread
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        // some time consuming operation
        int result = IntStream.range(0, n).sum();
        // after the result is ready do something with it.
        consumer.accept(result);
    });
    t.start();
}
```

and to use this method do:

```
methodA(1000000, System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit old, but nevertheless... I found the answer of Peter Wilkinson nice except for the fact that it does not work for primitive types like int/Integer. 
The problem is the `.getClass()` for the `parameters[i]`, which returns for instance `java.lang.Integer`, which on the other hand will not be correctly interpreted by `getMethod(methodName,parameters[])` (Java's fault) ...

I combined it with the suggestion of Daniel Spiewak ([in his answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180097/dynamically-find-the-class-that-represents-a-primitive-java-type)); steps to success included: catching `NoSuchMethodException` -> `getMethods()` -> looking for the matching one by `method.getName()` -> and then explicitly looping through the list of parameters and applying Daniels solution, such identifying the type matches and the signature matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorldAnonymousClasses {

    //this is an interface with only one method
    interface HelloWorld {
        public void printSomething(String something);
    }

    //this is a simple function called from main()
    public void sayHello() {

    //this is an object with interface reference followed by the definition of the interface itself

        new HelloWorld() {
            public void printSomething(String something) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + something);
            }
        }.printSomething("Abhi");

     //imagine this as an object which is calling the function'printSomething()"
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        HelloWorldAnonymousClasses myApp =
                new HelloWorldAnonymousClasses();
        myApp.sayHello();
    }
}
//Output is "Hello Abhi"
```

Basically if you want to make the object of an interface it is
not possible, because interface cannot have objects.

The option is to let some class implement the interface and then call that function using the object of that class.
But this approach is really verbose.

Alternatively, write new HelloWorld() (*oberserve this is an interface not a class) and then follow it up with the defination of the interface methods itself. (*This defination is in reality the anonymous class).
Then you get the object reference through which you can call the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface, and Create the Same Interface Property in Callback Class.

```
interface dataFetchDelegate {
    void didFetchdata(String data);
}
//callback class
public class BackendManager{
   public dataFetchDelegate Delegate;

   public void getData() {
       //Do something, Http calls/ Any other work
       Delegate.didFetchdata("this is callbackdata");
   }

}
```

Now in the class where you want to get called back implement the above Created Interface.
and Also Pass "this" Object/Reference of your class to be called back.

```
public class Main implements dataFetchDelegate
{       
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        new Main().getDatafromBackend();
    }

    public void getDatafromBackend() {
        BackendManager inc = new BackendManager();
        //Pass this object as reference.in this Scenario this is Main Object            
        inc.Delegate = this;
        //make call
        inc.getData();
    }

    //This method is called after task/Code Completion
    public void didFetchdata(String callbackData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(callbackData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest and easiest way is by creating a reusable model and trigger.... https://onecompiler.com/java/3wejrcby2?fbclid=IwAR0dHbGDChRUJoCZ3CIDW-JQu7Dz3iYGNGYjxYVCPCWfEqQDogFGTwuOuO8