# could anybody please explain what is callback method with some sample example in java?

Tags: java

could anybody please explain what is callback method with some sample example in java?

Comment: Posible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443708/callback-functions-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Callback usually refers to an event-oriented approach whereby a listener is registered with a specific class and is called back whenever an event occurs.  For example, the event could correspond to a user pressing a key or some data being received over TCP.

In the below example I've assumed the existence of a listener interface called `EventListener`.  `EventListener`s are registered with an "observable" `EventStream` class (note that I've omitted the `addListener` and `removeListener` methods for clarity).  Once started the event stream creates a separate thread that deals with the job of receiving events and calling back each listener.  I've used a separate thread to illustrate that a callback method could be called by a thread other than the one used to register the listener.

```
public class EventStream {
  private final List<EventListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventListener>();

  public void start() {
    // Create thread responsible for performing I/O, creating and
    // broadcasting Event objects to any registered listeners.
    Thread t = new Thread(...);
    t.start();
  }

  // Notification method.  Called by internal event stream thread.
  protected void fireEventReceived(Event e) {
    for (EventListener l : listeners) {
      l.eventReceived(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this by googling "callback java":

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip10.html

If you start using google yourself, you could often get faster answers.

Comment: I think the idea is that Stackoverflow becomes the source for Google (regarding questions about programming), not the other way...

Comment: Valid advises to use google first should be left as comments to the original question, to my opinion.

Comment: @Carlos Then I learned something. Basically in every other forum I participate(d) posing questions to which answers can easily be googled or found in in wikipedia is frowned upon.

@Andreas I will do that for google advises in future.

Comment: true, agreed... same here. IMO having links pointing to some *official* sites like SUN, Javaworld or Wikipedia is OK (eventually accompanied by an abstract). Soon Google will point to Stackoverflow anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

A callback or upcall is an invocation of a method in a higher layer that the caller. Particularly in procedural programming we typically think of higher layer calling into lower layers. Application code calling library code, and finer stratifications. A callback reverses the raltionship, by having a reference to the method passed to the lower layer.

In Java this is typically implemented by implementing an interface, as the language does not (yet) have a concept of a lone method reference - it's all objects with runtime classes. Often these will be implemented as anonymous inner classes. On the other hand it might be outer classes perhaps with some other configuration, such as servlets and applets.

The callback may be synchronous all asynchronous. Synchronous callbacks are called back during a single execution of a lower layer method, for instance as in the [Execute Around Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341971/what-is-the-execute-around-idiom). They may be called back later as in AWT/Swing events (same thread) or say `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` (different threads).