# How to get back a reply through a message in Android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, message

How can I get back a Message reply to the Activity in Android? Say an Activity ask one of a  java object (Running Thread) to do something and give back the reply. How java object can know to reply back to the activity who sent the message? I have many activities and many objects communicate with each other.

 How can I implement this with Android Messages? I don't want to use broadcasting here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use Messenger for this. Can set the messenger as the reply path. And inside message it hold the handler it should give back the reply.

```
final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler); 
. 
.
msg.replyTo = messenger;  // set the handler of the reply activity.
msg.setData(mBundle);     // if any additional data available put to a bundle
destinationClass.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);



// in destination class

Messenger msger = msg.replyTo;  // get the message sender's details.

Message msg2 = Message.obtain();
msger.send(msg2);                // send the reply message again to the sender
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Handler` if you are trying to communicate with a Thread. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

> Handler is part of the Android system's framework for managing
>   threads. A Handler object receives messages and runs code to handle
>   the messages.

A nice article on this topic: [AndroidBackgroundProcessing](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: Ok. To call handler I must know the Activity instance, right?
ActivityName.handler.sendMessage(); My problem is how to find the Activity name as activity and java objects are in separate locations.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is Callbacks. [Call backs in Java (code explanation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041522/call-backs-in-java-code-explanation) or an observer pattern http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html

Comment: I'm checking if anything android framework can support. without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Well, a not-so-clean way to do this is to pass your activity's handler's instance as a msg.obj. The receiver can then send back messages to it

Comment: What's the difference between sending an object in parcel and sending the object through msg.obj.

Comment: In parcel, you would need to implement parcelable interface. In msg.obj, there is no such requirement

Comment: Thanks Ankur but which one is better? Why two solutions for one problem.