# Java: How can we create callback function when "function pointer is prohibited"?

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the nearest substitute for a function pointer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122407/whats-the-nearest-substitute-for-a-function-pointer-in-java)
>   [Callback functions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443708/callback-functions-in-java)

I would like to ask some concept of the term **callback**.

What is the main purpose of using callback? Is it only for doing some async function? from the wiki, i can't get what does actually means.

This part of code is copied from [wiki- callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)

```
    void PrintTwoNumbers(int (*numberSource)(void)) {
        printf("%d and %d\n", numberSource(), numberSource());
    }

    /* One possible callback. */
    int overNineThousand(void) {
        return (rand() % 1000) + 9000;
    }

    /* Here we call PrintTwoNumbers() with three different callbacks. */
    int main(void) {
        PrintTwoNumbers(overNineThousand);
}
```

from the wiki, it said the we need to pass a **function pointer** as arguments to other functions in order to do a callback.

But in java, there is no way to pass-by-references when we call a function, can we make a callback function in Java just like above code?

Thanks

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443708/callback-functions-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122407/whats-the-nearest-substitute-for-a-function-pointer-in-java

Comment: What is the main purpose of using callback? The [Hollywood principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle) is a great analogy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up until now, Java has used interfaces and (sometimes anonymous) implementations of said interfaces to behave as callbacks.

For simple callbacks, you can use `java.util.Runnable` or [`java.util.concurrent.Callable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of defining your own interfaces.

Upcoming versions of Java will add better support for doing elegant callbacks, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous class instance implemening interface with only one method e.g. [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html):

```
Callable<Integer> function = new Callable<Integer>() {
  Integer call() {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

And then in the code that uses a callback just call it like that:

```
int result = function.call();
```

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are what you use if you do not have an OO language. C++ inherited them from C. Instead, take a look at the Strategy design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

not really the only thing you can pass is object references but with the right interface...

```
return new CallBack(){
public void call(){
   //...
}
}
```

generics for ret value and args will be a nice expansion