# How to specify function types for void (not Void) methods in Java8?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm playing around with Java 8 to find out how functions as first class citizens. I have the following snippet:

```
package test;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class Test {

    public static void myForEach(List<Integer> list, Function<Integer, Void> myFunction) {
      list.forEach(functionToBlock(myFunction));
    }

    public static void displayInt(Integer i) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Integer> theList = new ArrayList<>();
      theList.add(1);
      theList.add(2);
      theList.add(3);
      theList.add(4);
      theList.add(5);
      theList.add(6);
      myForEach(theList, Test::displayInt);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is pass method `displayInt` to method `myForEach` using a method reference. To compiler produces the following error:

```
src/test/Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
      list.forEach(functionToBlock(myFunction));
                   ^
  symbol:   method functionToBlock(Function<Integer,Void>)
  location: class Test
src/test/Test.java:25: error: method myForEach in class Test cannot be applied to given ty
pes;
      myForEach(theList, Test::displayInt);
      ^
  required: List<Integer>,Function<Integer,Void>
  found: List<Integer>,Test::displayInt
  reason: argument mismatch; bad return type in method reference
      void cannot be converted to Void
```

The compiler complains that `void cannot be converted to Void`. I don't know how to specify the type of the function interface in the signature of `myForEach` such that the code compiles. I know I could simply change the return type of `displayInt` to `Void` and then return `null`. However, there may be situations where it's not possible to alter the method I want to pass somewhere else. Is there an easy way to reuse `displayInt` as it is?

Comment: Here's a Java Lambda Shape Reference you might find useful: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HzSpbHhaB6igjkc0me2hTYehgfNkYCENw7io7IQI9vM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 333, accepted):

You are trying to use the wrong interface type. The type [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) is not appropriate in this case because it receives a parameter and has a return value. Instead you should use [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) (formerly known as Block)

The Function type is declared as

```
interface Function<T,R> {
  R apply(T t);
}
```

However, the Consumer type is compatible with that you are looking for:

```
interface Consumer<T> {
   void accept(T t);
}
```

As such, Consumer is compatible with methods that receive a T and return nothing (void). And this is what you want.

For instance, if I wanted to display all element in a list I could simply create a consumer for that with a lambda expression:

```
List<String> allJedi = asList("Luke","Obiwan","Quigon");
allJedi.forEach( jedi -> System.out.println(jedi) );
```

You can see above that in this case, the lambda expression receives a parameter and has no return value.

Now, if I wanted to use a method reference instead of a lambda expression to create a consume of this type, then I need a method that receives a String and returns void, right?.

I could use different types of method references, but in this case let's take advantage of an object method reference by using the `println` method in the `System.out` object, like this:

```
Consumer<String> block = System.out::println
```

Or I could simply do

```
allJedi.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The `println` method is appropriate because it receives a value and has a return type void, just like the `accept` method in Consumer.

So, in your code, you need to change your method signature to somewhat like:

```
public static void myForEach(List<Integer> list, Consumer<Integer> myBlock) {
   list.forEach(myBlock);
}
```

And then you should be able to create a consumer, using a static method reference, in your case by doing:

```
myForEach(theList, Test::displayInt);
```

Ultimately, you could even get rid of your `myForEach` method altogether and simply do:

```
theList.forEach(Test::displayInt);
```

**About Functions as First Class Citizens**

All been said, the truth is that Java 8 will not have functions as first-class citizens since a structural function type will not be added to the language. Java will simply offer an alternative way to create implementations of functional interfaces out of lambda expressions and method references. Ultimately lambda expressions and method references will be bound to object references, therefore all we have is objects as first-class citizens. The important thing is the functionality is there since we can pass objects as parameters, bound them to variable references and return them as values from other methods, then they pretty much serve a similar purpose.

Comment: By the way, `Block` was changed for `Consumer` in latest releases of the JDK 8 API

Comment: The last paragraph glosses over some important facts: Lambda expressions and method references are more than a syntactic addition. The JVM itself provides new types to handle method references more efficiently than with anonymous classes (most importantly `MethodHandle`), and using this, the Java compiler is able to produce more efficient code, e.g. implementing lambdas without closure as static methods, thus preventing the generation of additional classes.

Comment: And the correct version of `Function<Void, Void>` is `Runnable`.

Comment: @OrangeDog This is not totally true. In the comments to `Runnable` and `Callable` interfaces it's written that they are supposed to be used in conjunction with [threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). The annoying consequence of that is that some static analysis tools (like Sonar) will complain if you call `run()` method directly.

Comment: Coming purely from a Java background, I wonder what in particular are the cases where Java cannot treat functions as first-class citizens even after the introduction of functional interfaces and lambdas since Java8?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo can I use a consumer that consumes more than one parameter? (3 in my case...)

Comment: @Daniel There’s a `BiConsumer` in the standard library. If it’s more than two, though, you’ll need to define your own functional interface.

Answer (score 30):

When you need to accept a function as argument which takes no arguments and returns no result (void), in my opinion it is still best to have something like

```
  public interface Thunk { void apply(); }
```

somewhere in your code. In my functional programming courses the word 'thunk' was used to describe such functions. Why it isn't in java.util.function is beyond my comprehension.

In other cases I find that even when java.util.function does have something that matches the signature I want - it still doesn't always feel right when the naming of the interface doesn't match the use of the function in my code. I guess it's a similar point that is made elsewhere here regarding 'Runnable' - which is a term associated with the Thread class - so while it may have he signature I need, it is still likely to confuse the reader.

Comment: In particular `Runnable` does not allow checked exceptions, making it useless for many applications. Since `Callable<Void>` is not useful either, you need to define your own it seems. Ugly.

Comment: In reference to the checked exception issue, Java's new functions in general struggle with that. it's a huge blocker for some things like the Stream API. Very poor designing on their part.

Answer (score 7):

Set return type to `Void` instead of `void` and `return null`

```
// Modify existing method
public static Void displayInt(Integer i) {
    System.out.println(i);
    return null;
}
```

OR

```
// Or use Lambda
myForEach(theList, i -> {System.out.println(i);return null;});
```