# Java 8 lambda Void argument

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, void

Let's say I have the following functional interface in Java 8:

```
interface Action<T, U> {
   U execute(T t);
}
```

And for some cases I need an action without arguments or return type. So I write
something like this:

```
Action<Void, Void> a = () -> { System.out.println("Do nothing!"); };
```

However, it gives me compile error, I need to write it as

```
Action<Void, Void> a = (Void v) -> { System.out.println("Do nothing!"); return null;};
```

Which is ugly. Is there any way to get rid of the `Void` type parameter?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319787/how-to-specify-function-types-for-void-not-void-methods-in-java8

Comment: If you need an action, as you defined it, it's not possible. However, your first example could fit in a `Runnable`, which what you are looking for `Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Do nothing!");`

Comment: @BobTheBuilder I don't want to use a Consumer as suggested in that post.

Comment: @AlexisC. the problem is that Runnable cannot be made a subtype of my function type.

Comment: In java if in method signature you have return type - you must return something in method implementation.

Comment: Matt's answer makes the types work, but what does the caller do when it gets a null return value?

Comment: You could cross fingers and hope that suggestions 2 & 3 in [this post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2015-January/009233.html) get accepted for Java 9!

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The syntax you're after is possible with a little helper function that converts a `Runnable` into `Action<Void, Void>` (you can place it in `Action` for example):

```
public static Action<Void, Void> action(Runnable runnable) {
    return (v) -> {
        runnable.run();
        return null;
    };
}

// Somewhere else in your code
 Action<Void, Void> action = action(() -> System.out.println("foo"));
```

Comment: This is the cleanest workaround you could get, IMO, so +1 (or with a static method in the interface itself)

Comment: Konstantin Yovkov's solution below (with @FunctionalInterface) is a better solution, because it does not involve generics and does not require extra code.

Comment: @uthomas Sorry, I don't see an answer involving `@FunctionalInterface`. He merely says, that it's not possible to extend it...

Comment: Hi @Matt, sorry. I reacted too fast. For the given question you answer is perfectly valid. Unfortunately, my vote is locked, so I cannot remove my -1 on this answer.

Two notes:
1. Instead of `Runnable` action should take a custom `@FunctionalInterface` something called `SideEffect`,
2. the need for such helper function highlights that something weird is going on and probably the abstraction is broken.

Answer (score 900):

Use [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) if it takes nothing, but returns something.

Use [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) if it takes something, but returns nothing.

Use [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) if it returns a result and might throw (most akin to [`Thunk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) in general CS terms).

Use [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) if it does neither and cannot throw.

Comment: As an example I did this to wrap "void" return call : `public static void wrapCall(Runnable r) { r.run(); }`. Thanks

Comment: Does not help if it must throw a checked exception, unfortunately.

Comment: Consumer allows only one input parameter

Comment: As completion for this answer, which wouldn't be worth an edit: you can also use BiConsumer (takes 2, returns 0), Function (takes 1, return 1) and BiFunction (takes 2, returns 1). Those are the most important to know

Comment: One note here is that [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) cannot throw and really best used when you want to execute asynchronously. If you want to have a functional interface more akin to [Thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk), you should use [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), which can throw.

Comment: Is there anything like Callable (which throws an exception in its call() method) but does require any return value?

Comment: Also: `Function<T, R>` if it takes a single argument of type T and returns a value of type R. AFAIK It cannot throw.

Comment: I wish JDK could reuse the Unix Philosophy terminology: cantrip, filter, source and sink

Comment: I wanted a strongly typed NO_OP in the spirit of `@FunctionalInterface`, instead of using `Runnable`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985309/501113

Answer (score 459):

I think this table is short and usefull:

```
Supplier       ()    -> x
Consumer       x     -> ()
BiConsumer     x, y  -> ()
Callable       ()    -> x throws ex
Runnable       ()    -> ()
Function       x     -> y
BiFunction     x,y   -> z
Predicate      x     -> boolean
UnaryOperator  x1    -> x2
BinaryOperator x1,x2 -> x3
```

As said on the other answers, the appropriate option for this problem is a `Runnable`

Comment: Don't forget `BiConsumer: x, y -> ()`!

Comment: I think Java lacks of RunnableThrowingException () -> () throws ex... (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398040/363573)

Comment: Tysvm for this table. I have reified and extended it into a Google Sheet document I've shared here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HzSpbHhaB6igjkc0me2hTYehgfNkYCENw7io7IQI9vM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 43):

The lambda:

```
() -> { System.out.println("Do nothing!"); };
```

actually represents an implementation for an interface like:

```
public interface Something {
    void action();
}
```

which is completely different than the one you've defined. That's why you get an error.

Since you can't extend your `@FunctionalInterface`, nor introduce a brand new one, then I think you don't have much options. You can use the `Optional<T>` interfaces to denote that some of the values (return type or method parameter) is missing, though. However, this won't make the lambda body simpler.

Comment: The problem is that your `Something` function cannot be a subtype of my `Action` type, and I can't have two different types.

Comment: Techmically he can, but he said he wants to avoid it. :)

Answer (score 33):

You can create a sub-interface for that special case:

```
interface Command extends Action<Void, Void> {
  default Void execute(Void v) {
    execute();
    return null;
  }
  void execute();
}
```

It uses a [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) to override the inherited parameterized method `Void execute(Void)`, delegating the call to the simpler method `void execute()`.

The result is that it's much simpler to use:

```
Command c = () -> System.out.println("Do nothing!");
```

Comment: Where is this Action<Void,Void> coming from? Neither the Swing nor the JAX-WX Action interfaces have such an generic interface?

Comment: @luis.espinal: `Action<T, U>` is declared in the question.....

Comment: Hahaha, how the heck did I miss that? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In the same way of @rado answer with the parameters and the description:

```java
/*----------------------
Represents an operation
that accepts two input
arguments and returns no
result.
*/
BiConsumer<T,U>         (T x, U y)  -> ()


/*----------------------
Represents a function
that accepts two arguments
and produces a result.
*/
BiFunction<T,U,R>       (T x, U y)   -> R z


/*----------------------
Represents an operation
upon two operands of the
same type, producing a
result of the same type
as the operands.
*/
BinaryOperator<T>       (T x1, T x2) -> T x3


/*----------------------
A task that returns a
result and may throw an
exception.
*/
Callable<V>             ()    -> V x   throws ex


/*----------------------
Represents an operation
that accepts a single
input argument and returns
no result.
*/
Consumer<T>             (T x)   -> ()


/*----------------------
Represents a function that
accepts one argument and
produces a result.
*/
Function<T,R>           (T x)   -> R y


/*----------------------
Represents a predicate
(boolean-valued function)
of one argument.
*/
Predicate<T>            (T x)   -> boolean


/*----------------------
Represents a portion of
executable code that
don't recieve parameters
and returns no result.
*/ 
Runnable                ()    -> ()


/*----------------------
Represents a supplier of
results.
*/
Supplier<T>             ()      -> T x

/*----------------------
Represents an operation 
on a single operand that
produces a result of the
same type as its operand.
*/
UnaryOperator<T>        (T x1)  -> T x2
```

fonts:

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

[3] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible, because function definitions do not match in your example.

Your lambda expression is evaluated exactly as

```
void action() { }
```

whereas your declaration looks like

```
Void action(Void v) {
    //must return Void type.
}
```

as an example, if you have following interface

```
public interface VoidInterface {
    public Void action(Void v);
}
```

the only kind of function (while instantiating) that will be compatibile looks like

```
new VoidInterface() {
    public Void action(Void v) {
        //do something
        return v;
    }
}
```

and either lack of return statement or argument will give you a compiler error.

Therefore, if you declare a function which takes an argument and returns one, I think it is impossible to convert it to function which does neither of mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible. A function that has a non-void return type (even if it's `Void`) has to return a value. However you could add static methods to `Action` that allows you to "create" a `Action`:

```
interface Action<T, U> {
   U execute(T t);

   public static Action<Void, Void> create(Runnable r) {
       return (t) -> {r.run(); return null;};
   }

   public static <T, U> Action<T, U> create(Action<T, U> action) {
       return action;
   } 
}
```

That would allow you to write the following:

```
// create action from Runnable
Action.create(()-> System.out.println("Hello World")).execute(null);
// create normal action
System.out.println(Action.create((Integer i) -> "number: " + i).execute(100));
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a static method inside your functional interface

```
package example;

interface Action<T, U> {
       U execute(T t);
       static  Action<Void,Void> invoke(Runnable runnable){
           return (v) -> {
               runnable.run();
                return null;
            };         
       }
    }

public class Lambda {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Action<Void, Void> a = Action.invoke(() -> System.out.println("Do nothing!"));
        Void t = null;
        a.execute(t);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Do nothing!
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference which functional interface can be used for method reference in cases method throws and/or returns a value.

```
void notReturnsNotThrows() {};
void notReturnsThrows() throws Exception {}
String returnsNotThrows() { return ""; }
String returnsThrows() throws Exception { return ""; }

{
    Runnable r1 = this::notReturnsNotThrows; //ok
    Runnable r2 = this::notReturnsThrows; //error
    Runnable r3 = this::returnsNotThrows; //ok
    Runnable r4 = this::returnsThrows; //error

    Callable c1 = this::notReturnsNotThrows; //error
    Callable c2 = this::notReturnsThrows; //error
    Callable c3 = this::returnsNotThrows; //ok
    Callable c4 = this::returnsThrows; //ok

}


interface VoidCallableExtendsCallable extends Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    Void call() throws Exception;
}

interface VoidCallable {
    void call() throws Exception;
}

{
    VoidCallableExtendsCallable vcec1 = this::notReturnsNotThrows; //error
    VoidCallableExtendsCallable vcec2 = this::notReturnsThrows; //error
    VoidCallableExtendsCallable vcec3 = this::returnsNotThrows; //error
    VoidCallableExtendsCallable vcec4 = this::returnsThrows; //error

    VoidCallable vc1 = this::notReturnsNotThrows; //ok
    VoidCallable vc2 = this::notReturnsThrows; //ok
    VoidCallable vc3 = this::returnsNotThrows; //ok
    VoidCallable vc4 = this::returnsThrows; //ok
}
```

Comment: Please add some more context.  This looks interesting, but its meaning is not immediately obvious.