# Java function signature for (() -> {})

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

What's a valid function signature for `funSig`?

```
funSig(() -> System.out.println());
```

Comment: What is `funSig`?

Comment: May be related: [How do I define a method which takes a lambda as a parameter in java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604703/how-do-i-define-a-method-which-takes-a-lambda-as-a-parameter-in-java-8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 lambda Void argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945627/java-8-lambda-void-argument)

Comment: no - because it's not a void argument :)

Comment: this question is legitimate. It should have not been closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Runnable` would work,

It matches a void return and no params.

```
Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println();
```

And obviously it doesn't need to be `Runnable`, any `Functional Interface` that matches the signature will do.

Comment: thanks, for some reason I was looking for an interface in `java.util.function`