# returning an object from an inner method

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, return-value

I am trying to build a separate class for firebase methods, 
one of these methods is to return an Object User

```
    public User getUser(){
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.child("users").child(mUserID).child("user_info").getValue(User.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
        return user;
    }
```

returning the user gives me an error.
is it possible to return the User user from the inner onDataChange() method?
and how?

Comment: You can use RxJava Observable or create interface callback listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible because Firebase is asynchronous, and you're effectively trying to convert this method back into a blocking call by making the calling method "wait for" a returned object.

The appropriate pattern here is

1) make an interface.

```
public interface OnUserResult {
    void onUser(User u);
}
```

2) pass interface into void method
3) pass result back to Callback interface

```
public void getUser(final OnUserResult callback) {
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.child("users").child(mUserID).child("user_info").getValue(User.class);
           if (null!=callback) callback.onUser(user);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

4) Rewrite the calling method to not expect a returned object

```
// Bad: User user = api.getUser();

// Good 
api.getUser(new OnUserResult() {
    @Override public void onUser(User u) {
         // Update the UI, or whatever 
        // Do not assign a global user variable here either 
    } 
});
// any external user variable will (usually) still be null here
```

Libraries such as RxJava help you to implement this pattern in other ways

Comment: it works!.. thank you very much. but honestly i don't understand most it. can you please recommend for me a tutorial or something to help me understand it?

Comment: This is not specific to Android. It's just a generalized programming pattern for event driven systems... https://stackoverflow.com/q/443708/2308683

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to return anything from an inner class..
But one can initialize an instance variable inside the inner class , making it accessible to all members of the class

Answer (score 0):

Is user declared in the scope of the class? Because otherwise I don't know how `getUser()` is accessing the user it is returning.  Try declaring user in `getUser()` instead of inside `onDataChange` because the user in `onDataChange` is only in the scope of that method.

Also, if `onDataChange` is never called, there is never a declared User and it would return null

Comment: i tried this too. declared it in getUser(). but when i want to access it from inside the onDataChange() it asks me to make it final User. so i can't assign new value to it !!!

Comment: Your best bet would be making an interface then