# Is there a way for me to display the output of a Doubly Linked List class in JList of another class? Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, doubly-linked-list

Within my Java project I have a `class` for a Doubly Linked List, it runs fine putting output to the console window but I was wondering how should I go about getting the output onto a `JList` of another `JFrame` I have created? 
Cheers

Comment: Callbacks, my friend, callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `class` for your linked list does output to the console, the first thing you need to learn is to try and separate your concerns. Your linked list may or may not be outputted at certain method calls and may or may not be outputted to the console or your `JList`. Since you may intend (which already happened in your case) to reuse your doubly linked list in different use-cases, you need to implement your `class` in a very agnostic manner, without any assumptions about outputting it on the console.

Now, what should your doubly linked list support in order to ensure that it will work in separate environments:

- instantiation
- element adding
- element removal
- element iteration using a callback

Take a look here for examples of callback: [Callback functions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443708/callback-functions-in-java)

Now, if you need to use your class at a console application or a swing application, you can specify a callback and call the element iteration.