# Is there a way to output the java data type to the console?

Tags: java, types, casting

I'm trying to debug a program I inherited. This program contains Strings, array lists and collections, lots of casting between types, and I need to do some String manipulations (`substring`, etc.)

The data *look* like Strings when printed to the console (e.g., it's a line of text, like `Johnson, John` or `Chicago Region`), but my code is erroring out with various `index out of range` errors, suggesting that my code to cast to String isn't working.

I'd like to try to figure out what data types are coming into and leaving my methods to verify that the program is acting as expected. Is there any way to find a field type in Java? In a perfect world, I could generate console output at every step that would give me the data value and whether it's a String, array list, or collection. Can that be done?

Comment: By the way, if you're not getting a `ClassCastException`, then the cast to `String` *is* working.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Given an instance of any object, you can call it's getClass() method to get an instance of the Class object that describe the type of the object.

Using the Class object, you can easily print it's type name:

```
Integer number=Integer.valueOf(15);
System.out.println(number.getClass().getName());
```

This print to console the fully qualified name of the class, which for the example is:

```
java.lang.Integer
```

If you want a more concise output, you can use instead:

```
Integer number=Integer.valueOf(15);
System.out.println(number.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

getSimpleName() give you only the name of the class:

```
Integer
```

Printing the type of primitive variables is a bit more complex: see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180097/dynamically-find-the-class-that-represents-a-primitive-java-type) for details.

Answer (score 9):

For any object `x`, you could print `x.getClass()`.

Comment: I would do x.getClass.getName()

Comment: @PaulVargas `if(object == null){ sout("null")}`

Comment: And what about arrays? Arrays of objects or primitives?

Comment: An array of `int`s will print `[I`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

`instance.getClass()` is the way to go if you just want to print the type. You can also use `instanceof` if you want to branch the behaviour based on type e.g.

```
if ( x instanceof String )
{
   // handle string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getClass()` method.

```
Object o;
System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `.class.getName();` in any object