# How find data type of premtive variable in java

Tags: java

How get premtive variable data type in print statment .
tell method that tell about data type of variable?

Comment: Please provide the print statement.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438448/is-there-a-way-to-output-the-java-data-type-to-the-console

Answer (score 1):

If you are invoking a method like

```
System.out.printf("%d", 5);
```

then `System.out.printf` doesn't actually receive a primitive argument: the variadic parameter is of type `Object[]`, so the `5` will be autoboxed to `Integer` in this case.

However, there is no token listed in the [formatter syntax documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) which will print the parameter's type in the string.

---

You can write overloaded methods which are specialized for each of the primitive types:

```
String typeName(boolean _) { return "boolean"; }
String typeName(byte _) { return "byte"; }
String typeName(short _) { return "short"; }
String typeName(int _) { return "int"; }
String typeName(long _) { return "long"; }
String typeName(float _) { return "float"; }
String typeName(double _) { return "double"; }
String typeName(char _) { return "char"; }
```

You can then invoke this like:

```
int a = 5;
float f = 4.5f;
System.out.print(typeName(a));  // outputs "int"
System.out.print(typeName(f));  // outputs "float"
```

Comment: int a=5; float=4.5; System.out.printf("Datatype of a");

Comment: good  Thanx for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with primitive types, only objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can print Wrapper Type, not primitive type. Hope this will help :

```
int i=5;
System.out.println(((Object)i).getClass().getName());
```

Answer (score -1):

For any object `x`, you could print `x.getClass().getName()`

Comment: Assuming 'premtive' means 'primitive', this does nothing to help answer the question.