# Get Class of a primitive number type from a String

Tags: java, primitive

Is there a simple way to get Class of a primitive number type from String?

For `"42"` the method would return `int.class`,

for `"25.8"` it would return `float.class`, etc...

I only need to check for number types, so the method does not have to be concerned about booleans and bytes.

I am asking, just in case anyone knows about a library method that can do this thing.

Comment: try to use switch case to check every type and the correct one is your type

Comment: You can use a regex to classify the string.

Comment: This reference should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180097/dynamically-find-the-class-that-represents-a-primitive-java-type

Comment: @w88 that question concerns only Strings that have form e.g. `"java.lang.String"` not that have form of a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to get Class of a primitive number type from String?

AFAIK ... No there isn't.

One reason is that many numeric strings can have multiple representational types; e.g. `"42"` could represented as:

- a `byte`, `short`, `int` or `long`,
- a `float` or `double`,
- wrapper types for the above,
- a `BigInteger` or a `BigDecimal`, or ...
- a `String`, `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.

And the flip side is that a number like `"25.8"` probably doesn't have a *precise* representation in any of the primitive types or their wrappers.

If there is (often) not single correct answer, it is not surprising that there is no general solution provided by the Java SE libraries, or any of the commonly user 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: thanks for answer. I thought so, but I'll wait a bit, just in case anyone knows a library method

Comment: And don't forget about the localization (globalization) settings. Sometimes there are different decimal seperators in different globalization settings.