# Is there a way to compare a primitive type with its corresponding wrapper type?

Tags: java, types, wrapper

I have an ArrayList of objects `ArrayList<Object> arrList` containing wrapper classes for the various primitives as well as an array of type Parameter `Parameter[] parameters`

Both have the same number of elements. I would like to loop through the elements of parameters and compare that their types are the same as those in arrList.

I realise there are many ways of comparing an int with Integer.lang.Integer such as simply casting the int to an Integer and then comparing but my Parameter[] has ints, booleans, floats etc and my ArrayList has Integers, Floats, Booleans etc, so I am not always sure what the value will be.
I don't think I really understand how primitives are represented. For example, I assumed the following statement would return true but it does not:

```
 Boolean bool=true;                                  
 System.out.println(boolean.class==bool.getClass());
```

I have this the relevant bit of code:

```
    for(int i=0; i<parameters.length; i++){
        if(parameters[i].getType()==arrList.get(i).getClass()){
           doSomething();
        }
    }
```

But the comparison always returns false even when it compares boolean.class to Boolean.getClass()

Thanks for any help/advice

Comment: A `Boolean` object would return `Boolean.class` through `getClass()`.

Comment: The two classes `boolean.class` and `Boolean.class` are different. `boolean.class` is usually only used when using reflection as it represents the primitive `boolean` parameters and return types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the static field `TYPE` that every wrapper class has. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180139/7424948))

```
for(int i=0; i<parameters.length; i++){
    if(parameters[i].getType()==arrList.get(i).getClass().getField("TYPE").get(null)){
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

You could also compare the lowercase class names but you would have to handle `int` and `char` as special cases.

Alternatively you could create a `Map<Class, Class>` between primitive classes and wrapper classes.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem perfectly. Don't really understand the `.get(null)` call but it works.

Comment: @M.Santos. We are using reflection here. The `getField()` call returns a `Field`. Normally, once you have your Field, you get its value with `myField.get(myInstance)`. But here we don't have an instance since it's a static field. As written in [the documentation of get()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) : *If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null.*