# How to know if the value of a string is a java data type or not

Tags: java, string

I have a string tmp like that: `String tmp = "value";`
I want to know if the value of `tmp` is a data type in java or not, in this case not because "value" is different then "int" or "double"...
but if `tmp` hold "int" so it is a data type.
I want to know how to check this, if there is an enumeration of data type of java mention it please.

Comment: how would you possible know that? there are millions of people out there creating new datatypes every single hour. you want to check them all?

Comment: What would it mean to be an "int", as in `String tmp="int"` or `String tmp="1";`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but maybe could help -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313605/1984767

Comment: Why do you want to know this after all? What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: For primitive types, you have the full list here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: You will check if it is data-type and then do what?

Comment: If by data-type you mean primitive, then there isn't really a built in list.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180097/dynamically-find-the-class-that-represents-a-primitive-java-type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically find the class that represents a primitive Java type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180097/dynamically-find-the-class-that-represents-a-primitive-java-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java itself doesn't have a built-in list of primitive data types (at least not that I'm aware of), but luckily it's a small and closed list, so you could just create it yourself. For any non-primitive class, you could just attempt to call `Class.forName` on it:

```
private static final Set<String> PRIMITIVES = 
    new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList("byte", "char", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "boolean"));

public static boolean isType(String s) {
    if (PRIMITIVES.contains(s)) {
        return true;
    }

    try {
        Class.forName(s);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignore) {
        retrun false;
    }
    return true;
}
```